# Proving $\sum E\left[\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}\right] < \infty$. Then:$\sum X_n<\infty$ a.s.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, independence

$\{X_n\}$ are independent variables, $EX_n=0, EX_n^2=1$. $\sum E\left[\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}\right] < \infty$. Then:$\sum X_n<\infty$ a.s.

My ideas so far:
I tried to use Kolmogorov three series theorem to prove the convergence of $\sum X_n<\infty$.
(1) $\sum p(|X_n|>1)<\infty$
(2) $\sum E(X_nI{_{|X_n|\leq1}})$ converges. 
(3)$\sum \operatorname{Var}(X_n^2I{_{|X_n|\leq1}}) \leq \sum E(X_n^2I{_{|X_n|\leq1}}) \leq\ \sum 2E\left(\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}I{_{|X_n|\leq1}}\right)\leq \sum 2E\left(\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}\right)<\infty$ .
The convergence of series(3) is easy but I don't known how to prove the convergence of (1)(2) (For series (1), the Markov inequality seems not work. For series(2), Since $EX_n=0$, then the convergence of $\sum E(X_nI{_{|X_n|\leq1}})$ is equivalent to the  convergence of $\sum E(X_nI{_{|X_n|>1}})$, but I still cannot proof this).

Thanks in advance for any tips or help in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a good idea. For the first one, note that $ \mathbb P(|X_n| > 1) \le \mathbb E[|X_n|1_{|X_n| > 1}]$ by Markov's inequality. Moreover, for any $x \ge 1$ we have an inequality (pointwise-one) $x \le \frac{2x^2}{1+x}$ (it's equivalent due to $x(1+x) \le x^2+x^2$ for $x \ge 1$), hence using this one under $\mathbb E[\cdot]$ sign, $$ \sum_n \mathbb P(|X_n| > 1) \le \sum_n \mathbb E\left[|X_n|1_{|X_n|>1}\right] \le 2\sum_n \mathbb E\left[\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|} 1_{|X_n|>1}\right] \le 2\sum_n \mathbb E\left[\frac{X_n^2}{1+|X_n|}\right] < \infty $$

For the second one, we note that $\mathbb E[X_n1_{|X_n| < 1}] = -\mathbb E[X_n1_{|X_n|>1}]$ as you said, and then apply just the same reasoning as above (actually part of the above is exactly the convergence of $\sum_n \mathbb E[X_n1_{|X_n|>1}]$.

Since you've showed your work on the third series (which is correct), I won't repeat the reasoning.

Comment: Thank you for helping me again :)

Comment: To be precise, $0 = \mathbf{E} X_n = \mathbf{E} X_n \mathbf{1}_{|X_n| \leq 1} + \mathbf{E} X_n \mathbf{1}_{|X_n| > 1} \implies \mathbf{E} X_n \mathbf{1}_{|X_n| \leq 1} = - \mathbf{E} X_n \mathbf{1}_{|X_n| > 1}$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you Gauss